# How to make Jupyter Notebook look in the right place for a module?

Tags: kernel, python, python3

Using a Jupyter Notebook running with the python2 kernel, I tried to import `emcee` and I got an error message:

```
File "/home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/emcee/ensemble.py", line 84
    parameter_names: Optional[Union[Dict[str, int], List[str]]] = None,
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

apparently because I am using the python2 kernel.

I then installed ipykernal using: `python3 -m pip install ipykernel`

I then opened a Jupyter Notebook using the Python3 kernel. I tried to `import emcee` but I had the same problem. It was still looking for the `emcee` module in the python2 path.

I then did `pip3 install emcee`, opened a Jupyter Notebook (python3 kernel) but I still have the same issue.

I think I need to tell Jupyter Notebook to look for the python3 version of emcee, but I'm not sure how to. I just tried:

```
export PYTHONPATH='/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/'
```

But again, this didn't fix it. I checked the `sys.path` in my Juoyter Notebook and the new python path didn't seem to be added.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jupyter Notebook wasn't really using the python3 kernel even though it said it was:

My python3 kernel was located: `/home/damejia/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3`

The `kernel.json` file was:

```
{
 "argv": [
  "python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
```

But "python" just points to my python2. I changed "python" to "python3" and everything worked.